# react-native build release APK failed

Tags: android, react-redux, react-native

I'm doing crossplatform app for mobile devices in react-native. And when I try to create release APK it fails with error:

```
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 
':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' property '$1' during up-to-date check.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file 
'/Users/developer/dummy_app/.buckd/sock' as it does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or 
--debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
24 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 23 up-to-date
2:16:52 AM: Task execution finished 'assembleRelease'.
```

I consider solving a similar problem, like, deleting .buckd/sock file from root folder and invalidatecache/restart, but didn't help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue here with Buck

After deleting the whole `.buckd` folder, the Task `:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`  passed successfully after !

Hope this could help someone !